# "This all happened", in here, what's the meaning of "all"?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

---

### "This all happens in the middle of winter."  What's the meaning of "all" in this sentence?

The above is a part of a synopsis of "Fargo" movie.
And I've heard a lot "it all happened...", "this all happened..."

And I've searched some dictionaries about "all". Then I guessed that in here "all" is "adverb" and means "completely" That's because its location is before verb in the sentence.

But I still cannot fully understand the above sentence meaning. Could you help me understand the meaning of "all" in here please?

Comment: It may mean: All of these happen in the middle of winter. I think it's a good idea that you provide more context.

Comment: Thank @Arham 27 for your answer!! Here's the whole synopsis.  ----------  that's the one(=DVD) where a car salesman hires two criminals to kidnap his wife so that he can get money from her rich farther. But everything goes wrong. *This all happens in the country town in the middle of winter. The police officer  find the criminals in the end.

Comment: Why is "this all happens in the middle of winter", not "these all happen in the middle of winter"?

Comment: I thought "these" matches "all" because grammatically they are plural. So "whole of these" or "all of these" make sense but I didn't think "whole of this" or "all of this" doesn't make sense. Maybe I might be wrong....

Comment: Apparently it means that the whole story related to the kidnap completely happens in the middle of winter [and not later or sooner]. The context is the key.

Comment: 'all' is NOT always plural, e.g. in "All of the food has gone."

Comment: I really appreciate your help. They are very helpful and now I got the gist of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'All' is a predeterminer [used to refer to the whole quantity or thing](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/all). The sentence is no different from "all (of) this happens in the middle of winter".

This phenomenon is called **quantifier float** and addressed in [Payne (2010)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://pages.uoregon.edu/tpayne/UEG/UEG-additionalreading-ch10-Qfloat.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj_oeiNn4DfAhVKLo8KHe1SATQQFjABegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw2QzPeXdO8bC0uxKdMS12GW).